# How to get screen available height in javascript in Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, windows, height, screen

I was trying to get the screen available height (not include task bars and etc) in Javascript. screen.availHeight in Mac OS/Linux gives me exactly what I need. However, in Windows 10 screen.availHeight returns longer than I expect. It seems to include the length of task bars as well.

How can I get the maximum available height not including the task bars and etc in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

**So I'm pretty sure using jQuery is the solution!**

This code will work quite fine:

```
$(window).height();   // browser viewport height
```

Also I'm sure this is not problem of Windows, it's sounds like some kind of browser problem :)

Have you tried to use `document.height` also? Is this not working either?

```
$(document).height(); // HTML document height
```

Comment: I was trying to do window.open to popup a window. Would like to have height of the window to be screen's maximum available height not including the task bars and etc. But in window 10, screen.availHeight returns the height which includes the task bars. In this case, $(window).height or $(document).height() does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
   window.innerHeight;

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height of the window you can do `window.innerHeight`

If you want the height of the screen you can do `window.screen.height`